# How to show exit confirm dialog when user clicks Home button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exit

I need to show the exit confirm dialog when user pressing the Home button. If yes, need to exit the application.

Is it possible to show when pressing the Home button?

Comment: There are probably methods you can hook onto. I know there is an applicationwillenterbackground delegate you can hook onto for instance. The question is more should you. I don't think that fits with Apples UX guidelines, and I've not seen any apps that do this.

Comment: It depends on which type of your program. If you want to develop a app on App Store,I believe this function will be reject by APPLE.But you can do this on a jailbreak tweak.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would probably cause your app to be rejected

From the [Apple HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1):

**Always Be Prepared to Stop**

iOS apps stop when people press the Home button to open a different app or use a device feature, such as the phone. In particular, people don’t tap an app close button or select Quit from a menu. To provide a good stopping experience, an iOS app should:

Save user data as soon as possible and as often as reasonable because an exit or terminate notification can arrive at any time.
Save the current state when stopping, at the finest level of detail possible so that people don’t lose their context when they start the app again. For example, if your app displays scrolling data, save the current scroll position. To learn more about efficient ways to preserve and restore your app’s state, see “State Preservation and Restoration”.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can stop the app from terminating or going into the background.  You can tell it is about to go background through the app delegate applicationWilResignActive or be terminated by applicationWillTerminate.